# Using Typescript static methods in vue templates

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I wanted to use Typescript static methods in vue templates

```
export class ProjectUI {
  static budget(p: Project): string {
    if (p.budget > 0) {
       return p.budget + "EUR"
    } else {
       return "No budget."
    }
}
```

and in a template

```
:value="ProjectUI.budget(p)"
```

and I don't want to use filters. Vue doesn't find the method when compiling templates though (as ProjectUI.budget is TS syntax).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only use the functions and variables that are defined on your component. So in your case you could expose the ProjectUI class as a data variable:

```
data() {
    return {
        ProjectUI
    }
}
```

Comment: are there any downsides/negatives to doing this?

Comment: Yeah surely this makes the `ProjectUI` constructor reactive, which will possibly hurt performance / memory use?

Comment: How would a solution look like, that uses the class style? In such case I would have to create a `private ProjectUI: ProjectUI = ProjectUI;` right? This gives me a "missing properties" error.